# Digikam: What is the extension for exportet keyboard shortcut scheme?

Tags: import, keyboard-shortcuts, export, digikam

Using digikam 5.6.0 I am able to export shortcut schemes.
(Menu: Settings→Configure Shotcuts…→ Manage Schemes» → more Actions → Export Scheme)

This results in an extension-less file (contents in typical [ini format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file))

**However: How do I import back in again?** The shortcut-Filter of the file dialog filters down to *something*, but I simply don't know what extension... no luck with guessing...

[image]

**Update**

At least, there's a workaround: past full, absolute path (inkl. filename) into the Location field at top, press import. Works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want .shortcuts.

Helpfully, the OS X version is pretty explicit on that point:

[image]

and when checking the import - the default is to only accept files with .shortcuts.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanx. Verified to also work on Linux (Ubuntu).